# When Calling Other Activity Method Showing NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

I have two activity (`PrivateContactActivity.java` and `AddContact.java`). Inside `PrivateContactActivity` have a method:-

PrivateContactActivity.java

```
public void databaseLoader() {
    privateList.clear();
    myDatabase = new MyDatabase(PrivateContactActivity.this);
    Cursor cursor = myDatabase.queryData();
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Contact Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String name, phone, email, address;
            name = cursor.getString(1);
            phone = cursor.getString(2);
            email = cursor.getString(3);
            address = cursor.getString(4);

            PrivateContactModel privateContactModel = new PrivateContactModel(name, phone, email, address);
            privateList.add(privateContactModel);
        }
    }
}
```

AddContact.java

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    PrivateContactActivity privateContactActivity = new PrivateContactActivity();
    privateContactActivity.databaseLoader();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

and when i am calling this method from `AddContact` activity then showing `NullPointerException`. Why this problem? I face this kind of problem often. I solved this from kind of problem in another way but don't know why this problem. Please explain me.

Comment: In your `AddContact` activity i suppose you added a contact in your database. You don't need to create a new instance of `PrivateContactActivity`. Just call `databaseLoader()` method in your `PrivateContactActivity` `onCreate()`

Comment: is AddContact an activity class? why is it overriding onBackPressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **absolutely positively cannot** instantiate an `Activity` with the keyword `new`. Only Android can instantiate Android components (`Activity`, `Service`, `BroadcastReceiver`, `Provider`). The `Context` isn't correctly set up when you instantiate an `Android` component using `new`, which is why you get a `NullPointerException`.

To get around this you can declare your method `databaseLoader()` as `static` and pass a `Context` argument into it which can be used as necessary. When calling this method from any `Activity` you can pass `this` as the `Context` argument.

---

Also, it isn't clear why you would need to load your database in `onBackPressed()`, since `onBackPressed()` just finishes the `Activity` anyway and it will be destroyed. This seems strange.

Comment: Thanks, Now i am clear about new Keyword. I used databaseLoader() inside onBackpressed() because after adding new contact i need to update my contact list(when i leave the AddContact activity). Now can you tell me about some little doubt? if we can't use NEW keyword for instantiate then how we can use other activity method or variable without using static keyword?

Comment: Within the `Activity` you can use all non-static variables and methods of the `Activity` class because they activity's `Context` has been set up correctly. If you want to call a method in an `Activity` from **outside that `Activity`** then you **must declare it `static`** and you must pass in a reference to a `Context` (if that is required by the `Activity`. In general, if you have a method in an`Activity` class that is used by other classes, the method probably doesn't belong in the `Activity` class to begin with. It should be moved to a separate utilities class (and probably made `static`).

Comment: In your case,  the reason you are having problems is that your architecture is wrong. It isn't the job of `AddContact` to reload the list of contacts that belongs to `PrivateContactActivity`.  This is something that `PrivateContactActivity` should do by itself when control returns to it. You should have `PrivateContactActivity` launch `AddContact` by using `startActivityForResult()` and then refresh the contact list in `PrivateContactActivity.onActivityResult()`. Then you don't need to make the method `static` or call it from outside the `Activity` and you don't need override `onBackPressed()`